# How can I add and remove password with Android NFC Tags?

Tags: android, kotlin, nfc, mifare, ntag21x

I followed tutorial to write data to NFC Tags. I want to be disable write and format tags for no password user, but i can remove password when i write data or format tag.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 methods to stop writing to a tag, there is password protect the write operation or disable write which is irreversible.

When you set a password, you have also have to set what memory areas are password protected. If you don't change what is protected by the password then by default nothing is protected by the password (including changing the password).